# Opposite of 座ります

Tags: words, word-requests

Is there an "opposite" of 座ります?

Comment: Please, try to do your own research before asking such basic questions that can be answered at Google easily. Once you have done your research, If you still have specific doubts or problems that arise as a result of your efforts, please post all the steps you followed and your attempts to solve that problems and Japanese Stackexchange usera will provide useful help for sure. Thank you!

Comment: “Opposite” isn’t actually a well-defined concept in linguistics, so it doesn’t really make sense to ask what the opposite is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the opposite of 座ります (sit down) is:

> 立【た】ちます  (stand up).

Comment: I thought the opposite of sitting down is not sitting down...

Comment: Isn't not sitting down the _negative_ of sitting down?

Comment: Also, if the OP was trying to learn how to formulate the negative form of a verb, why then picking a particular word (座ります) instead of using a generic like Vます, or a bunch of examples?

Comment: Sorry, tongue in cheek comment — of course I meant to point out that, as in @snailvehicle's comment on the question, it's not always clear what should be the "opposite" of some word. (Maybe on a night train, the opposite of sitting down would be lying down...?) I remember being at school playing "opposites" where the opposite of "cat" is obviously "dog" and the opposite of "sun" is "moon", the opposite of "pen" is "pencil", etc.

Comment: Well, I don't know. I remember my English lessons at school (I'm not a native English speaker, I don't know what tongue in cheek means, sorry) where we were taught the words "sit down", "stand up" as opposite, complementary, call it whatever you want. I don't agree with snaivehicle here, I don't think it makes no sense to ask for "the opposite" of a word. We are learning, please. I'm no linguist, but it was so clear to me what the OP was asking for, and it seems like my answer solved his doubt anyway, so there was communication here. I can concede that opposite might be unclear though.

Comment: On the other hand, I agree that this question provides little value to the community and that it requires more effort from OP's side, as btw I pointed out in a comment.